# Evento click botão

Tags: java, swing

Adiciono alguns botões assim:

```
JButton bt;
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    bt = new JButton("BT : " + i);
    bt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
    bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // fazer algo
        }
    });

    jPanel.add(bt);
}
```

Preciso de uma ação para cada botão, vou dar um exemplo bem simples. Supomos que tenho um vetor de 10 posições, com números de 1 a 10. Ou seja, tenho uma posição no vetor para cada botão inserido. Ao clicar no botão preciso exibir o numero da posição do vetor referente ao botão clicado.

Botao 1 - exibe posição 1 do vetor
Botao 2 - exibe posição 2 do vetor
Botao 3 - exibe posição 3 do vetor .... e assim por diante

Como posso fazer isso no evento de click do botao?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Geração de botões dinamicamente](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118667/gera%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-bot%c3%b5es-dinamicamente)

Answer (score 2):

Mantenha tudo no laço e declare um `final` com o que você quer escrever/manipular.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    JButton bt = new JButton("BT : " + i);
    final Integer valor = Integer.valueOf(i);
    bt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
    bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Valor : " + valor);
        }
    });
    jPanel.add(bt);
}
```

Comment: Pra que o `Integer>valueOf` se o cast de int pra integer é automático? Veja no [ideone](http://ideone.com/vVKakw)

Comment: Apenas por clareza @DiegoF.  De qualquer forma valeu.

Answer (score 2):

Use o método [**`setActionCommand()`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setActionCommand-java.lang.String-) para definir uma ação para o botão. Depois você pode pegar esse valor quando o evento for disparado:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    bt = new JButton("BT : " + i);
    bt.setActionCommand(String.valueOf(i));
    bt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
    bt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Índice: " + e.getActionCommand());
        }
    });
    jPanel.add(bt);
}
```

Se precisar desse valor como `int`, pode usar o método [**`Integer#parseInt`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-).

Comment: Não conhecia esse comando, interessante. Não sou o OP, mas seria interessante um exemplo do uso disso para gerar dentro do for, como ele sugere na pergunta.