# Como gerar vários botoes coma mesma variável e pegar eles separadamente

Tags: java, variáveis, button

Olá, vou colocar a parte importante do codigo aqui e então explicarei o que quero fazer.

Main:

```
public static JButton sala;
public static int contagemTurmas = 0;

botaoSalvar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {   
            gerarTableTurma(turmaName.getText(), contagemTurmas, panelCriados);
        }
    });

sala.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            System.out.println(sala.getText());
            turmaName.setText(sala.getText());
        }
    });
```

Parte que gera os vários botoes apartir da vairavel `sala`

```
public static void gerarTableTurma(String turma, int posicao, JPanel panel) 
{   
    sala = new JButton(turma); //turma = JTextArea
    sala.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 30));
    sala.setBounds(10, 11 + (contagemTurmas * 43), 792, 32);
    panel.add(sala);

    contagemTurmas ++;

    panel.repaint();
}
```

Eu gostaria de pegar o evento de um botão, porem não sei o botão, por isso criei vários botoes na mesma variavel,sendo assim não importa o botão clicado, eu saberia qual seria apenas testando a variavel `sala`, como eu posso fazer isso ?? já que quando eu clico em um dos botoes não acontece nada

Comment: Sinceramente não entendi nada do que você explicou.

Comment: @DiegoF Basicamente quero criar vários botoes, porem não quero ter que criar uma variável para cada um deles, quero poder alterar eles e saber se algum deles foi clicado a partir de apenas uma variavel

Comment: Creio que [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/118722/28595) resolva perfeitamente seu problema :)

Comment: @DiegoF Resolveu perfeitamente, Obrigado.